# Nvidia Driver installation issue on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I have installed linux mint 19 on HP pavilion laptop. Unable to Nvidia drivers-though i tried, system is not recognizing it. X Server is showing blank when opened in GUI.

Details below

**inxi -SMCGx**

```
System:
  Host: suhas-HP-Pavilion Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.8 
  Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Pavilion Notebook 
  v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: HP model: 820A v: 82.25 serial: <root required> UEFI: Insyde v: F.07 
  date: 05/27/2016 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-6200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Skylake rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19200 
  Speed: 500 MHz min/max: 400/2800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 500 2: 500 
  3: 500 4: 500 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 520 vendor: Hewlett-Packard Skylake GT2 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.2 direct render: Yes
```

**lspci -nnk |egrep -A3 -i "3D|VGA"**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [103c:820a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] [10de:134d] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM108M [GeForce 940MX] [103c:820a]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
```